# How can i do a Transactional method in Liferay 7.3?

Tags: java, database, transactions, liferay, liferay-7.3

I create a `scheduler` that in the same transaction delete rows in `DB` and insert new rows after delete.
But if the adding of rows fails, I lost my data because the delete was correctly.
How I can delete and add with the same transaction to avoid losing data in case of errors?
I want to do a delete and two different adds in the same table.

Comment: Is your code encapsulated in service builder or external to it? E.g. can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: is inside a service builder

Answer (score 2):

There are three cases:

1. **If your code were everything starts is in a method a LocalServiceImpl class generated by service builder:**

   - Liferay automatically creates a transaction that begins in the first method called in the first LocalServiceImpl and is propagated in the internal calls that that method does to the methods other LocalServiceImpl classes.
   - So the idea is to have a entry point in a LocalServiceImpl method where Liferay will automatically start the transaction, and from that method, call the other LocalServiceImpl methods that must be executed in the same transaction.
   - Note: by default only the methods that change data (add, update, delete) are creating a new transaction.
2. **If your code is in a MVCActionCommand**, you can use the BaseTransactionalMVCActionCommand as the parent class and implement your code in the **doTransactionalCommand** method.

   - Your code will be wrapped in a new transaction
   - For more information see: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-kernel/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/portlet/bridges/mvc/BaseTransactionalMVCActionCommand.java
3. **If your code is outside of the LocalServiceImpl classes, you can always manually create a transaction using TransactionInvokerUtil:**

   ```
    import com.liferay.portal.kernel.transaction.*;
    import com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.*;
    import java.util.concurrent.*;

    private _invokeTransactionally(Callable callable)
        throws Throwable {

        Class<?>[] rollbackForClasses = new Class<?>[1];

        rollbackForClasses[0]=Exception.class;

        try {
            TransactionInvokerUtil.invoke(
                TransactionConfig.Factory.create(
                    Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackForClasses), callable);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
             // handle the exception
        }
    }

    Callable callable = new Callable<Void>() {
        Void call() throws Exception {
             // here insert your code

             return null;
        }
    }
   ```

   - Your code should go inside the Callable class.
   - To execute it: **_invokeTransactionally(callable);**

Comment: But the methods in LocalServiceImpl don't have to be private ? Because i create one method that inside there are calls to three private method (delete,add,add).. but if the delete it's ok, and first add no, i lost any data in database..

Comment: You are free in your choice of parameters - e.g. you can create one `*LocalServiceImpl` method like `updateData(List addTheseObjects, List deleteTheseObjects)` and implement this method as a loop through the objects. `updateData` will open the transaction, and it will be propagated to the following `add` and `delete` calls within `updateData's` implementation (until you return from `updateData`.

Comment: My ancient memory says that transactions are opened automatically based on method names - can you confirm or deny, @Jorge? (e.g. `add*`, `update*`, `delete*` would be candidates, while `doSomething()`isn't)

Comment: Yes, thats true, @OlafKock,  by default add*, update* and delete* are considered transactional.
I think that other methods are annotated with the `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)` annotation, so they only use the transaction if it is already created in the parent one, but they don't create a new one, as readOnly is true

Comment: I create method `public void updateContacts(List<com.google.api.services.admin.directory.model.User> users,List<Person> contacts)` that inside call three methods to (delete, add, add) but if first add isn't ok, i lost the date because delete it was ok

Comment: Method delete it jus a for to delete all concacts. Methods add to add different type of contacts